# why am I getting a precise bus fault exception (PRECISERR) on what looks like a perfectly fine aligned access (cortex-m7)

Tags: exception, assembly, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I'm getting a HardFault that results from a forced/escalated Precise Bus Fault Exception, as indicated by the `PRECISERR` bit in the `BFSR` register, and I can't seem to figure out why it is occurring. The exception occurs from within vendor-supplied startup code that previously executed fine, and I cant see any alignment or memory-related issues.

The offending instruction is `ldrlt  r0, [r1], #4` on the first iteration through the loop, where the value stored in `r1` is `0x00040458`

The full instruction sequence is shown below, where other relevant symbols used in `r2` and `r3` are defined in the comments

```
/*     Loop to copy data from read only memory to RAM. The ranges
 *      of copy from/to are specified by following symbols evaluated in
 *      linker script.
 *      __etext: End of code section, i.e., begin of data sections to copy from.
 *      __data_start__/__data_end__: RAM address range that data should be
 *      __noncachedata_start__/__noncachedata_end__ : none cachable region
 *      copied to. Both must be aligned to 4 bytes boundary.  */

    ldr    r1, =__etext          /* equal to 0x00040458 */
    ldr    r2, =__data_start__   /* equal to 0x20000000 */
    ldr    r3, =__data_end__     /* equal to 0x20000224 */

.LC0:
    cmp     r2, r3
    ittt    lt
    ldrlt   r0, [r1], #4  /* <---- exception triggered here */
    strlt   r0, [r2], #4
    blt    .LC0
```

The offending address listed in `BFAR` is `0x00040458`, which corresponds to the value in `r1` and **is a perfectly valid 32-bit aligned address within the ITCM region (0x0 --> 0x0007FFFF).**

Not sure what else could be causing this exception if the memory access itself looks fine. The exception was introduced by expanding the `.text` section in my linker file, as shown below

```
MEMORY
{
  m_interrupts  (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00000400
  m_text        (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000400, LENGTH = 0x00074000  /* changed from LENGTH = 0x0003FC00 */
  m_data        (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00020000
  m_data2       (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x20200000, LENGTH = 0x00020000
}
```

If it isn't an alignment issue, I'm not sure what it could be? But `0x00040458` is most definitely word-aligned, as is `0x0004045C` which results from the `#4` offset to the `ldr` instruction.

**Also, why is `0x0004045C` not shown in `BFAR`, since the cortex-m7 TRM says the `ldr` instruction applies the offset to the target register value before the memory access occurs??**

Full exception registers shown below for completeness

[image: SCB exception regs]

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with Cortex-M; especially fault handlers.  However, on the Cortex-A devices a bus fault can result if the peripheral is not ready.  Besides alignment, system clocks and power (domain) can cause this type of fault.  Did something change in hardware or some system configuration?

Comment: this is flash to ram so both should be up, granted there may be a chip where they arent.

Comment: what chip is this (cortex-m7 is not a chip), are you hitting the end of the mirrored flash for example on an stm32?

Comment: @old_timer NXP iMX RT1051

Comment: @artlessnoise Unfortunately there have been no changes in hardware or system configuration/clocking. And there are no peripherals in use here, only a simple load from and address in ITCM into SRAM

Comment: @old_timer oh and flash isn't even involved here. This is purely RAM to RAM. Copying ITCM into regular SRAM

Comment: so that is not it as you know the flash is zero based.

Comment: ldr    r1, =__etext          /* equal to 0x00040458  ITCM

Comment: @old_timer 0x00040458 is an address in ITCM (RAM)

Comment: I stands for instruction D for data ITCM DTCM

Comment: flash at 0x00000000 sram at 0x20000000

Comment: thus the reason for the bootstrap to do this copy yes?

Comment: m_text        (RX)  read and execute not RWX

Comment: ITCM is tightly coupled instruction RAM. The ROM boot loader copies text from flash into RAM before this code is executed. We are executing from RAM the entire time.

Comment: this chip has no internal flash, and we are not executing from external flash either. The ROM copies code from flash to ram then hands off control to the ResetHandler shown above